# Firebase keeps giving me error Could not find country code file

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have followed the google firebase start up instructions for setting up firebase authentication however I keep on receiving the error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not find country code file'

Ive added all of the podFiles Im not sure what file could be missing how can I fix this. Ive been following the [FireBase Tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui?authuser=0)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,FUIAuthDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        // You need to adopt a FUIAuthDelegate protocol to receive callback
        authUI!.delegate = self
        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            FUIGoogleAuth(),
            FUIPhoneAuth(authUI:FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!),
            ]
        authUI!.providers = providers

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        let sourceApplication = options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String?
        if FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()?.handleOpen(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication) ?? false {
            return true
        }
        // other URL handling goes here.
        return false
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread will describe the issue you're facing:

[Link](http://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/304)

Just make sure that your FirebaseUI pod is updated to `4.3.1`.